# How to use asp.net signalr with android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, signalr, retrofit

I have mobile app which has Chat option and i implemented api using asp api
and singalr hub for chatting . can anybody tell me how to make my android app call hubs and i use retofit to call api in android

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SignalR Java Client](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.signalr/signalr/1.0.0/jar) in our Android application. This is specifically for **ASP.NET Core** SignalR though. The java client for classic SignalR is no longer supported.

Comment: thanks for help .. i am beginner in singalR i did not know asp.net signalR is gone and the replacement is signalR core now i have to learn it to use SignalR Java Client